What mathematical object defines a dual space norm?
I am currently a physics undergraduate, and for one of my recent homeworks I had to demonstrate the following relation.
For wave functions $\psi^1(r_1)$, $\psi^2(r_2)$, and $\psi(r_1,r_2)$ such that $\psi^{1,2}(r_{1,2})$ represent fermions and $\psi(r_1,r_2)$ represents the mixed macroscopic state represented by the relation $\psi(r_1,r_2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\psi^1(r_1)\psi^2(r_2)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\psi^1(r_2)\psi^2(r_1)$,
the norm squared of the function $\psi(r_1,r_2)$ is given by $\bracket{\psi|\psi}=\frac{1}{2}\bracket{\psi^1(r_1)\psi^2(r_2)| \psi^1(r_1)\psi^2(r_2)}+\frac{1}{2}\bracket{\psi^1(r_1)\psi^2(r_2)| \psi^1(r_1)\psi^2(r_2)}\pm\Re[{\psi^{1*}(r_1)\psi^{2*}(r_2)\psi^2(r_1)\psi^1(r_2)}]$.
This is fairly trivial and also can be taken as fact for the purposes of the question I am asking. In order to demonstrate this, I had to recognize that $\Re[{\psi^{1*}(r_1)\psi^{2*}(r_2)\psi^2(r_1)\psi^1(r_2)}]= \Re[{\psi^{1}(r_1)\psi^{2}(r_2)\psi^{2*}(r_1)\psi^{1*}(r_2)}]$ (since $\Re[f]=\Re[f^*]$), and that the norm of a function onto itself should map from dual space $D$ to some scalar in $\mathbb{R}$ (so naturally we must take the real component at the end).
However, this feels very arbitrary and taking the real component at the end feels akin to throwing a bandaid over our function to cover up a problem to satisfy our expected output more than an action motivated by rigor. This leads me to suspect that I am missing something—either that we take the real component at the end because this is physics and the imaginary component of complex numbers are not real (and mixed states can lead to imaginary numbers that we don’t want in our physically-defined output), or that
a. a norm is not a function and there is a difference between an operation and a function that becomes significant in this case,
b. norms on dual spaces do define a function, but functions such that $f:D\rightarrow S$ where $S\subseteq D$ require that $im(f)=S{\{f(d)\forall d\in D\}}$ for $S\{f(d)\forall d\in D\}$ being defined as some operation that forms a set $\{f(d)\forall d\in D\|f(d)\in S\}$ (this is my generalized equivalent for $\Re[\alpha]$), I am sure I am butchering function notation here, please let me know where I am wrong!
or c. something else entirely.
Thanks in advance. Let me know if there is any clarification needed! Links to resources if you have them would also be helpful.
(Also—a side note—does stack exchange have \usepackage support? It does not seem to have the bracket package preinstalled.)

This question is a little hard for me to follow: first you are using both the Dirac notation and the position-space wave functions at the same time, but you shouldn't. Write an inner product as either $\langle \psi | \chi \rangle$ or $\int \psi^\chi~dx$; don't mix them. Second, "the norm squared on the dual space of the function" doesn't make sense. There is no "dual space of a function". In any case, this seems to be a question about the norm on the space, not the dual space. Finally, in any case, the two real parts come out in the usual way: $(a+b)(a+b) = |a| ^2+ |b|^2 + 2 Re(ab)$.

Can you clarify your notation, and clarify the question?  Also, fix the notation in your post.  MathJax doesn't know what bracket is, and I'm interested in figuring out what you actually mean mathematically in that line, anyway.

My question is exactly what you said in the last half of your comment: that the square of a complex number will have some $2\Re (ab)$. This addition seems arbitrary beyond that the norm must be some function (in this case it appears to be a binary operation) that takes one element from a vector space and one from its dual space and maps it to the reals. Is it necessarily a projection onto the reals? Why else do we write Re?

Typical Dirac notation for a two-particle amplitude is $$\langle \phi_1,\phi_2|\chi_1,\chi_2\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^1}  dr_1 dr_2\phi_1^(r_1)\phi_2(r_2)^ \chi_1(r_1)\chi_2(r_2).$$ (There's a few options for how to write the bras and kets depending on your tastes, e.g., use of $\otimes$ to make the product explicit.) But this simplifies to $\langle \phi_1|\chi_1\rangle \langle \phi_2|\chi_2\rangle$, i.e., this two-particle amplitude is a product of one-particle amplitudes.

@Semiclassical I know how Dirac notation works here, but I'm not entirely convinced that the OP does.  For that reason, I'm asking them to clarify/rewrite the notation, and then address some of my other issues with the question. Otherwise, it's hard to tell what the OP is actually asking. As for your comment: that's true, but it seems like the OP is asking about the cross-terms (exchange terms) that appear due to the fact the state is a sum of two terms.

@Aspen. For a binary function on a space to be a norm, it has to satisfy the properties of being a norm. In this case, the norm is actually induced by an inner product, which also has to satisfy the properties of being an inner product, which is a fundamental part of the mathematical and interpretational apparatus of QM. I'm a little confused that you're at the point of doing things with identical particles in QM but haven't seen the use of inner products yet.
